# How i can get the append output as one by one outside the loop?

Tags: python, list, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying below python code

```
    for file in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix= folder_name):
        if (file.last_modified).replace(tzinfo = None) < last_modified_date:
            content.append('File Name: %s ---- Last Updated: %s' % (file.key,file.last_modified))
```

which ill give me output as below

```
['File Name: one.txt ---- Date: 2021-05-25 10:54:55+00:00', 'File Name: two.txt ---- Date: 2021-05-25 10:54:22+00:00', 'File Name: three.txt ---- Date: 2021-05-25 10:53:35+00:00', 'File Name: four.txt ---- Date: 2021-05-25 10:53:36+00:00',]
```

I'm expecting the same output as below outside the loop like below

```
File Name: one.txt ---- Date: 2021-05-25 10:54:55+00:00
File Name: two.txt ---- Date: 2021-05-25 10:54:22+00:00
File Name: three.txt ---- Date: 2021-05-25 10:53:35+00:00
File Name: four.txt ---- Date: 2021-05-25 10:53:36+00:00
```

Ive used as below but I couldn't pass this into a variable outside the loop.

```
    for file in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix= folder_name):
        if (file.last_modified).replace(tzinfo = None) < last_modified_date:
            content.append('File Name: %s ---- Last Updated: %s' % (file.key,file.last_modified))
            print (*content, sep = "\n")

a = print(*content, sep = "\n")
print(a)

result as None
```

Comment: What does "couldn't pass this into a variable outside the loop." mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd comment if i could, but since i can't i'll post an answer instead.
If you want to concatenate the list of strings into a single string :

```
my_str = ""
for k in content:
   my_str = my_str + k + "\n"
```

Or maybe create a string from the start (using python 3.6's [fstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)):

```
content = content + f"File Name: {file.key} ---- Last Updated: {file.last_modified}"
```

EDIT : it does seem to me that you are trying to concatenate strings. You cant use print for that because it always returns none.

I'd post a solution using [map](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map) if i saw any elegant one, but sadly i dont.